# Annotate plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have three vectors `a`, `b`, and `c` in numpy.

The vector `b` is computed as function of a: `b = f(a)`.

I'm plotting `b` with matplotlib as `plot(a, b)`.

The vector `c` has only x-positions. I want to annotate the plot at those x-positions in vector `c` with y-values near the values in vector `b`.

It would be easy if I could compute the y-value with `f(c)` and plotting at `(x,y) = (c,f(x))` but since I already got the vector `b` with computed values, I cannot recalculate the values from the values in `c`.

I've tried

```
plt.plt(a,b)

for x in np.nditer(c):
    plt.annotate("text", xy=(x, ?), xytext=(x, ?), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle="->"))
```

but I don't know what to do with the y-coordinate.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "It would be easy if I could compute the y-value with f(c) and plotting at (x,y) = (c,f(x)) but since I already got the vector b with computed values, I cannot recalculate the values from the values in c."

Comment: Replace `?` with `b[x]`?

Comment: Why can't you do: `b = f(a); d = f(c); plot(a,b); for x,y in zip(c, d); plt.annotate("text", xy=(x,y), ...)`

Comment: I also do not exactly understand what you want, my guess: do you want annotations at interpolated values of (a,b) for x's from c ?

Comment: @JanKuiken I thought about interpolating too... I guess the question is whether or not `f` is available.